# Prove that if$\ ||x|| \le ||x +\alpha y||$ then $x$ is perpendicular to $y.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

Prove that if$\ ||x|| \le ||x +\alpha y||$ (for every$\ \alpha \in\mathbb{ R}$  ) then $x$ is perpendicular to $y$ ($x$ and$ y$ are not$\ 0$)

We need to prove that $\ xy=0$, so I tried:

$\ ||x|| \le ||x +\alpha y||$

$\ ||x||^2 \le ||x +\alpha y||^2$

$\ x^2 \le (x +\alpha y)^2$

$\ x^2 \le x^2 + 2\alpha xy +\alpha^2y^2$

$\ 0 \le 2\alpha xy +\alpha^2y^2$

$\ 0 \le 2x +\alpha y$

But, this didn't got me anywhere and I'm confused on how to proceed

Comment: What is $\lVert x \rVert$ here?

Comment: Hey$x,y$ are vectors here not numbers !

Your work (attempt) does not make any sense.

Comment: Your last line does not follow from the 2nd-last line as $a$ may be negative,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
||x||^2=\langle x,x\rangle
$$

Using that and your previous work I find
$$
0\leq 2\alpha \langle x,y\rangle +\alpha^2||y||^2
$$

Let

$$
f(\alpha)=2\alpha\langle x,y\rangle +\alpha^2||y||^2
$$

using methods of calculus I find that $f$ is extremized when

$$
\alpha=-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{||y||^2}
$$

If I substitute this in

$$
f(-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{||y||^2})=-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{||y||^2}
$$

so the inequality at this value of $\alpha$ reads
$$
0\leq -\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{||y||^2}
$$

But $\langle x,y\rangle^2/||y||^2$ is a nonnegative number and if the inequality is to be satisfied we must conclude that $\langle x, y\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Even without calculus,  when $y\ne 0,$ complete the square of the quadratic $ \alpha^2 \|y\|^2+2\alpha (x,y)$...............+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Good point, yes one find the value of f at the vertex of the parabola and not need to perform any derivatives!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Write $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1$ parallel to $y$ and $x_2$ perpendicular to $y$. Then $x_1=ay$ for some scalar $a$.

Then
$$ ||x||^2 \le ||x -a y||^2 \\
||x_1+x_2||^2 \le ||x_2||^2 \\
||x_1\|^2+\|x_2||^2 \le ||x_2||^2$$
with the last line following from the fact that $x_1 \perp x_2$.

This implies that $x_1=0$ and hence $x=x_2$. Since $x_2 \perp y$ you are done.

Comment: How did you got that $\  ||x||^2 \le ||x -a y||^2$ ?

Comment: @DavidTomahak I set $\alpha =-a$ in the given inequality.

Comment: But this has to happen for every $\ \alpha$, also, why $x_1 \perp x_2$ ?

Comment: @DavidTomahak I defined $x_1$ to be the projection of $x$ on $y$. Then, by the definition of projection, $x_1 \perp x_2$.